# Can't get dokka to generate kotlin docs on gradle/android project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

I'm following the gradle plugin section in https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka .

I also tried the dokka-gradle-example example in https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/dokka-gradle-example .

The versions I'm using are:

```
android: '23.1.1'
dokka: '0.9.6'
gradle-android-plugin: '1.5.0'
kotlin: '1.0.0-rc-1036'
```

but I also tried with Dokka versions from 0.9 up to 0.9.7.

The relevant parts of the output are:

```
...

:app:dokka FAILED
:app:dokka (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 9,5,main]) completed. Took 0.766 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dokka'.
> com.intellij.mock.MockComponentManager.getPicoContainer()Lorg/picocontainer/MutablePicoContainer;

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dokka'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.mock.MockComponentManager.getPicoContainer()Lorg/picocontainer/MutablePicoContainer;
    at org.jetbrains.dokka.AnalysisEnvironment.createCoreEnvironment(AnalysisEnvironment.kt:78)
    at org.jetbrains.dokka.Utilities.DokkaModule.configure(DokkaModule.kt:50)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.dokka.DokkaGenerator.generate(main.kt:160)
    at org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask.generate(main.kt:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 54 more


BUILD FAILED
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm including the build files:

main `build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    ext.versions = [
            android: '23.1.1',
            anko: '0.8.2',
            dokka: '0.9.6',
            gradleAndroid: '1.5.0',
            kotlin: '1.0.0',
            spek: '0.1.194'
    ]

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$versions.gradleAndroid"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

Module `app/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$versions.gradleAndroid"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:${versions.dokka}"
    }

}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "http://repository.jetbrains.com/all"
    }
}

android {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.5

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                testCoverageEnabled true
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$versions.android"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$versions.android"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$versions.android"

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$versions.kotlin"

    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:$versions.anko"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$versions.anko"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$versions.anko"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$versions.anko"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$versions.anko"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-cardview-v7:$versions.anko"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7:$versions.anko"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-gridlayout-v7:$versions.anko"

    testCompile "org.jetbrains.spek:spek:$versions.spek"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$versions.kotlin"
}

dokka {
}
```

Comment: The documentation states: You have to apply the dokka plugin **after** the kotlin and the `com.android.application` plugins. Try to change the order.

Answer (score 3):

[UPDATE] This is reported as fixed with https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/pull/64.

---

The problem is that the current version of dokka is unable to pick up the *sourceSets* defined within the *android* block of the build.gradle file.

To work around this until it is fixed (I'll create an issue on the dokka Github repository), you can duplicate the sourceSets outside of the *android* block so that dokka can figure it out.

```
android {
  ...

  sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
  }
}

sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
  test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin
}
```

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me.

Comment: May you provide a link to the GitHub issue @eski. I'm having an issue running the dokka task due to an added `buildType`.

Comment: It was https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/61 but it looks like it's been fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Try Kotlin `1.0.0` release, with latest Dokka `0.9.7`.  You have a mismatch there.  The Kotlin plugin for Gradle and the Dokka versions must be compatible.  If you continue to have a conflict, it could be that you have another plugin conflicting with those.

Dokka `0.9.8` or newer no longer will conflict with the Kotlin compiler version if different.  It now contains what it needs embedded as shaded dependencies to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I've updated to  kotlin `1.0.0` and Dokka `0.9.7`, but it still not working. Also, I removed all the other plugins, staying with `anko`, `dokka` and `spek` only, but I still can't get it to work. I'm going to try to cut down `anko` in a separate project now.

Comment: @TiagoReul without more information of the build, hard to say what is going on.  You might need to try Kotlin forum discussions, or in Slack.

Comment: and Kotlin `1.0.3` with Dokka `0.9.6`. Argh.

Answer (score 2):

The dokka documentation deals with Android separately:

> If you are using Android there is a separate gradle plugin. Just make sure you apply the plugin after com.android.library and kotlin-android.

Try using `classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:${versions.dokka}"` as a dependency and adding `apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'` to the end of your plugin list, removing `apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'` from the beginning.

EDIT: This should be fixed, as noted in the comment below.

Comment: The android plugin was merged with the default one as of v0.10.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate Dokka documentatiton without Dokka plugin... Use [GradleMavenPush](https://github.com/Vorlonsoft/GradleMavenPush), it has `task androidDokka(type: Exec, dependsOn: dokkaInitializer)` and `task coreDokka(type: Exec, dependsOn: dokkaInitializer)`

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/Vorlonsoft/GradleMavenPush/master/maven-push.gradle'
```

Don't forgot to set `JAVADOC_BY_DOKKA = true`