# Generate kdoc and watch in browser

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-dokka

I don't know how to watch the generated `kdoc` in my Browser.

I'm developing for Android with Kotlin and added dokka as dependency in gradle.
The new `dokka` Task runs without Errors.

I added dokka as dependency in my Projects `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
...
classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:0.9.13"
}
```

and applied the plugin in my apps `build.gradle`

```
apply 'kotlin-android'
apply 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply 'org.jetbrains.dokka'
```

But I can't find the Output in the Project Folder. 
How can I watch the Output in my browser or where is it?

Thanks

Edit 1: IDE: Intellij; Kotlin Version: 1.1.1

Edit 2 (11.04.2017):

`build.Gradle`:

```
dokka {
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/docs"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815235/7441041) post solved the problem.

Apparently dokka is not able to pick up the `sourceSets {...}` defined in the `android {...}`-block.

Workaround:
duplicate the `sourceSets{...}` outside the `android{...}`-block

Answer (score 1):

You can control the output directory via the `dokka` task:

```
dokka {
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/docs"
}
```

To generate the docs, run `./gradlew dokka`

I've only done this for non-Android projects, but I believe the process is the same.

Comment: Error: `Cannot assign 'GString' to 'Class<OutputDirectory>'`.
It do not create the docs, if I run the task.

Comment: What does your dokka config block look like?

Comment: The same like yours.
But I read in the documentation at Github, that I have to apply `apply plugin: com.android.library`.
But I already applied `com.android.application` and both doesn't work at the same time and replacing one with the other doesn't work either.